# How would I open a folder using threads in ImageJ? (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, imagej

as part of a project in my ImageJ plugin, I need to open up to 3000 images as 
an ImageStack.
The user selects a folder containing all the files with

```
DirectoryChooser dirChoos = new DirectoryChooser("Select Folder");
String filePath = dirChoos.getDirectory();
```

My current method of opening the files is with

```
FolderOpener opener = new FolderOpener();
ImagePlus imp = opener.openFolder(filePath);
ImageStack stack = imp.getImageStack();
```

This works, however for larger folders this adds 4 or 5 minutes on to plugins running time. While I understand that opening large folders obviously takes more time, it would be nice if I could cut it down a bit.

The method I am trying to implement is

```
File folder = new File(filePath);
String[] listOfFiles = Folder.list();
Arrays.sort(listOfFiles); //　to make sure the stack is in the right order
```

By splitting it listOfFiles using Arrays.copyOfRange (into 3 for argument's sake) and into parts and passing them to an object that extends Thread

```
openFolder r1 = new openFolder(listOfFiles_part1);
openFolder r2 = new openFolder(listOfFiles_part2);
openFolder r3 = new openFolder(listOfFiles_part3);

new Thread(r1).start();
new Thread(r2).start();
new Thread(r3).start();
```

openFolder's method uses listOfFiles_part to form an array of ImagePlus instances from the files

```
int len = Array.getLength(listOfFiles_part)
ImagePlus[] impArray = new ImagePlus[len];
for (int a = 0; a < len; a++ ) {
     impArray[a] = new ImagePlus((listOfFiles_part[a]).getPath());
}
```

then, the impArrays are returned, and an ImageStack is formed from the arrays.

However, this does seem like a bit of an obtuse method and I haven't had too much luck implementing as of now.

Are there any better ways to use threads to get an ImageStack from the folder?
(Would using threads even necessarily speed up the process?)

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Where is the bottle neck, sorting or create new instance of ImagePlus ?

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque - the bottleneck is creating new instances of ImagePlus. My thinking is that if I'm using several threads to create ImagePlus instances and return them it'll be faster, but I have only limited experience in multithreading so any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more one approach.
If you use java 8 the parallel approach is the simplier

```
List<ImagePlus> impArray = new ArrayList<ImagePlus>();
listOfFiles_part.parallelStream()
.forEachOrdered(i -> impArray.add(new ImagePlus(i.getPath()));
```

Otherwise you may used threadpool because you don't know the optimized number of thread depending of the hardware.

Comment: Thank you! This definitely looks like a better method.